# Linear Search Code Shows that my item is not present.Please help me make corrections

Tags: c, algorithm, linear-search

> This is the function for linear search where i am only taking one variable x that is the to search for item variable

```
int lsrch(int x)
    {int i;
    int arr[6] = {2,4,5,76,2,1};
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(x==arr[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int a,b;
        a=lsrch(76);
```

> 76 is present so it should show its index location but it shows -1 for both meaning both are not present true for 2nd test case

```
        b=lsrch(99);
        printf("%d",a);
        printf("%d",b);
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code, and the problem should be very obvious very quickly.

Comment: Did you ignore compiler errors? I get "a.c:13:5: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]" which points to the problem of the misplaced return statement.

Comment: Please **do not** drastically edit the question. I have rolled it back to the original question. Changing the question so dramatically makes all of the answers invalid - especially changing the language from C to Python!. If you have another question, please ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry I got my mistake thanks alot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're breaking out of the loop too early.

```
int lsrch(int x)
{   
    int i;
    int arr[6] = {2,4,5,76,2,1};
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(x==arr[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
            return -1;      // Incorrect
    }
}
```

As written, as soon as your code finds a number that doesn't match `x`, it will return -1. It will never proceed to check the rest of the numbers in `arr`.

If you compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror`, the compiler will point out that you've made a mistake:

```
linsearch.c: In function ‘lsrch’:
linsearch.c:17:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

This means that you're not returning anything in the case that the loop finishes - causing undefined behavior.

---

The solution is to postpone the `return -1` until *after* the loop has exhausted all of the values in `arr`.

Also, your loop terminates when `i == 5` but you've not checked the last number in `arr`. Let's use a macro to avoid having to hard-code this value.

```
#define ARRAY_LEN(x)    (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

int lsrch(int x)
{   
    int i;
    int arr[] = {2,4,5,76,2,1};
    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_LEN(arr); i++)
    {
        if(x==arr[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;    // Nothing left to check
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks. Fixed with `ARRAY_LEN`.

Answer (score 2):

Logical Error in your code -
the foloowing part of your code was incorrect -

```
  if(x==arr[i])
   {
       return i
    }
    else 
         return -1
```

At the first pass itself if condition evaluates false and -1 is returned.

Correct Code -

```
int lsrch(int x)
   {
    int i;
    int arr[6] = {2,4,5,76,2,1};
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
   {
      if(x==arr[i])
      {
        return i;
      }

   }
       return -1;
   }

  int main()
  {
      int a,b;
      a=lsrch(76);
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Instead of just posting "fixed" code, perhaps you could tell the OP *what* you have changed? What makes this work?

Comment: @Some Programmer dude. I edited my answer. Thank You for feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
int lsrh(int x){
    int i,a[6]={2,4,5,76,2,1};
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(a[i]==x)
             return i;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

use this it will work